# Nashorn and ClassFilter

Tags: java, nashorn

Many examples, including [Oracle's own tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/api.html#sthref18) refers to some classes in the package `jdk.hashorn.api.scripting`. However it is not part of the standard Java 8 release. And when I tried to add it to my code, it tells me: `Access restriction: The type 'NashornScriptEngineFactory' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\lib\ext\nashorn.jar')`.

How can I use the ClassFilter feature in my java project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the current release `1.8.0_40`, not `1.8.0_25`. [From the release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u40-relnotes-2389089.html):

> New Java class-access Filtering Interface
>
> The jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ClassFilter interface enables you to restrict access to specified Java classes from scripts run by a Nashorn script engine. See Restricting Script Access to Specified Java Classes in the Nashorn User's Guide and 8043717 (not public) for more information.

Comment: I was looking for this u40 (for other issues), that I missed when it have come out at last. :-) Thanks.

Comment: I didnt't try but the release notes mention it.

Comment: Thanks, it was only my config error. (jar files still refered to u25)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  Even tried updating my Java SDK to see if that fixed it.  Updated to 1.8 u65 and had the same problem.  If you are using Eclipse, try going into

Windows->Preferences->Compiler->Errors/Warnings->**Deprecated and restricted API** change the **Forbidden reference(access rules)** from *Error* to *Warn*.

It opened up access for me and allowed me to build without any problems.